# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1

Tags: javascript, kotlin, gradle

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1.

```
This is my build.script

buildscript {
apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
repositories repos
dependencies {

    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION}"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${cordovaConfig.KOTLIN_VERSION}"
}

cdvHelpers.verifyCordovaConfigForBuild()
}

allprojects {
def hasRepositoriesGradle = file('repositories.gradle').exists()
if (hasRepositoriesGradle) {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
} else {
    apply from: "${project.rootDir}/repositories.gradle"
}

repositories repos
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I already added ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10' in buildscript and use classpath classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1" for classpath